# error while using ord() for wheel chair symbol in python

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x, python-unicode

I wish to create trained data for vehicle number detection. It is assumed that The vehicle number consists of digits 0 to 9 with special character. Please refer the example image[vehicle plate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzSuG.jpg). I am using the this image for creating trained data [training image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6K2I.png). The python code for generating trained data is given below.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

# module level variables ##########################################################################
MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 100

RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH = 20
RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 30

###################################################################################################
def main():
    imgTrainingNumbers = cv2.imread("training1.png")            # read in training numbers image

    if imgTrainingNumbers is None:                          # if image was not read successfully
        print "error: image not read from file \n\n"        # print error message to std out
        os.system("pause")                                  # pause so user can see error message
        return                                              # and exit function (which exits program)
    # end if

    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgTrainingNumbers, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)          # get grayscale image
    imgBlurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, (5,5), 0)                        # blur

                                                        # filter image from grayscale to black and white
    imgThresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred,                           # input image
                                      255,                                  # make pixels that pass the threshold full white
                                      cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,       # use gaussian rather than mean, seems to give better results
                                      cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,                # invert so foreground will be white, background will be black
                                      11,                                   # size of a pixel neighborhood used to calculate threshold value
                                      2)                                    # constant subtracted from the mean or weighted mean

    cv2.imshow("imgThresh", imgThresh)      # show threshold image for reference

    imgThreshCopy = imgThresh.copy()        # make a copy of the thresh image, this in necessary b/c findContours modifies the image

    _,npaContours, npaHierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgThreshCopy,        # input image, make sure to use a copy since the function will modify this image in the course of finding contours
                                                 cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,                 # retrieve the outermost contours only
                                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)           # compress horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leave only their end points

                                # declare empty numpy array, we will use this to write to file later
                                # zero rows, enough cols to hold all image data
    npaFlattenedImages =  np.empty((0, RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH * RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))

    intClassifications = []         # declare empty classifications list, this will be our list of how we are classifying our chars from user input, we will write to file at the end

                                    # possible chars we are interested in are digits 0 through 9, put these in list intValidChars
    intValidChars = [ord('0'), ord('1'), ord('2'), ord('3'), ord('4'), ord('5'), ord('6'), ord('7'), ord('8'), ord('9'),ord('♿')]

    for npaContour in npaContours:                          # for each contour
        if cv2.contourArea(npaContour) > MIN_CONTOUR_AREA:          # if contour is big enough to consider
            [intX, intY, intW, intH] = cv2.boundingRect(npaContour)         # get and break out bounding rect

                                                # draw rectangle around each contour as we ask user for input
            cv2.rectangle(imgTrainingNumbers,           # draw rectangle on original training image
                          (intX, intY),                 # upper left corner
                          (intX+intW,intY+intH),        # lower right corner
                          (0, 0, 255),                  # red
                          2)                            # thickness

            imgROI = imgThresh[intY:intY+intH, intX:intX+intW]                                  # crop char out of threshold image
            imgROIResized = cv2.resize(imgROI, (RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))     # resize image, this will be more consistent for recognition and storage

            cv2.imshow("imgROI", imgROI)                    # show cropped out char for reference
            cv2.imshow("imgROIResized", imgROIResized)      # show resized image for reference
            cv2.imshow("training_numbers.png", imgTrainingNumbers)      # show training numbers image, this will now have red rectangles drawn on it

            intChar = cv2.waitKey(0)                     # get key press

            if intChar == 27:                   # if esc key was pressed
                sys.exit()                      # exit program
            elif intChar in intValidChars:      # else if the char is in the list of chars we are looking for . . .

                intClassifications.append(intChar)                                                # append classification char to integer list of chars (we will convert to float later before writing to file)

                npaFlattenedImage = imgROIResized.reshape((1, RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH * RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))  # flatten image to 1d numpy array so we can write to file later
                npaFlattenedImages = np.append(npaFlattenedImages, npaFlattenedImage, 0) 
                cv2.imshow("imgROI", npaFlattenedImages)
                   # add current flattened impage numpy array to list of flattened image numpy arrays
            # end if
        # end if
    # end for

    fltClassifications = np.array(intClassifications, np.float32)                   # convert classifications list of ints to numpy array of floats

    npaClassifications = fltClassifications.reshape((fltClassifications.size, 1))
    print npaClassifications
    # flatten numpy array of floats to 1d so we can write to file later

    print "\n\ntraining complete !!\n"

#    np.savetxt(str(raw_input('Insert the name of the file (ex: "a.txt"): ')), npaClassifications,delimiter="\t")           # write flattened images to file
#    np.savetxt((raw_input('a.txt')), npaFlattenedImages) 
    np.savetxt('testimage_1.txt',npaFlattenedImages)         #
    np.savetxt('test1_1.txt',npaClassifications)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
#save(data)
#'a.txt'
#return data            # remove windows from memory
#def save(data): 
#    np.savetxt(str(input('Insert name of the list(ex: a.txt): ')), npaFlattenedImages)
#    return
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I got the error as

```
    intValidChars = [ord('0'), ord('1'), ord('2'), ord('3'), ord('4'), ord('5'), ord('6'), ord('7'), ord('8'), ord('9'),ord('♿')]

TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
```

How can i overcome this error?

Comment: Did you try using `unicode`s?

Comment: Try upgrading to python 3 :)

Comment: print (ord('♿')) . this works perfectly with python3.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2 you can try:

`u'♿'`

For example:

```
>>> ord(u'♿')
9855
```

Since you are using the `ord()` result as a mapping between key presses and labels, you can't use `♿` as a key press. I would try to use another ascii char to identify that case (like `ord('a')`).

You could replace that `a` later when reading from the keyboard:

```
elif intChar in intValidChars: 
    if intChar == ord('a'):
        intChar = ord('♿')
    intClassifications.append(intChar)
```

But probably, the training function doesn't even need that, as long as you remember to translate the prediction result.

Comment: It works now. Thanks JoseKilo. I am having another doubt While running the code,each digit in the training image got selected one by one then i supposed to enter the corresponding digit in keyboard for example if 0 got selected then i should enter 0 by keyboard. However, while wheelchair symbol got selected, i cannot enter '9855' completely, after pressing 9 in keyboard another number got selected in training image. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks JoseKilo. I am having another issue regarding wheelchair training. Can you please refer the question in the given link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360903/wheel-chair-symbol-training-in-python.